# Create SNS topic with email protocol and email address endpoint using serverless

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, serverless-framework, serverless

Creating Lambda functions using [serverless](https://serverless.com/) and I am trying to create a SNS topic with Email protocol. I want to then pass that arn as an ENV variable to a lambda function. I cannot find any documentation other than appending a topic to function in the creation process. Any help/examples is appreciated (I am working in python).

To elaborate, the below would create a function with an sns topic attached.:

```
functions:
  dispatcher:
    handler: dispatcher.dispatch
    events:
      - sns: dispatch
```

Looking to do "something" like (this does not work... just an example):

```
events:
  sns:
    topicName: thing
    subscription: 
      - endPoint: "myemail@thing.com"
      - protocol: "email"

functions:
  dispatcher:
    handler: dispatcher.dispatch
    environment:
      SNS_TOPIC: {Ref: ThingSnsTopic}
```

Ideally the sns part would be created outside of the functions, and the I could reference the sns arn and use it as a env var

Answer (score 0):

When using Serverless, you can use environment variables in your .yml file like this:

```
myProperty: ${env:MY_ENV_VAR}
```

If you want to bind it to SNS, your .yml file should look something like:

```
service: my-service


provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6


functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello

   events:
     - sns: ${env:MY_ENV_VAR}
```

Now, if you mean you'd like to accesss an Environment Variable from within your Lambda function, it will depend on what language you are coding on, but since you're using Python, it'd be something like:

```
import os

print("environment variable: " + os.environ['MY_ENV_VAR'])
```

***EDIT***: After the OP's comment, I think I fully understand the problem:

ARNs are predictable values. They're pretty much a concatenation of your region/user-id/topic-name, like this:

```
arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:00000000:aaa
```

If you provide an environment variable to your Serverless.yml, such as:

```
provider:
 name: aws
 stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
 environment:
  MY_SECRET: ${env:MY_ENV_VAR}
```

You could then programmatically [create a Subscription](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#subscription) to that topic based on the predictable subscription's ARN + the environment variable you defined.

Another option would be to define the [Outputs](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#reference-cloudformation-outputs) section on your .yml file and use the [CloudFormation Event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html#eventsources-cloudformation-create-request) to trigger a Lambda which will programatically create a subscription based on the outputted ARN

Comment: Yup, this is the easy part! This will create a SNS topic named $MY_ENV_VAR. The functionality I am looking for now is adding a subscription to that topic that is of email protocol and the endpoint is an email address.

Comment: @user2938093 did you get to try it? I didn't but I am sure it could work. Please let me know if you need further info.

Answer (score 0):

I create SNS topic and subscription in the resource section and then add a policy in the lambda role which can be assigned to lambda function, for example

```
Resources:  
  # SNS Topic Resources for email notification
  uploadProgressNotificationTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      DisplayName: "The notification topic for upload progress"
      TopicName: ${self:custom.uploadProgressNotificationTopicName}

  # SNS email subscription for upload completion
  emailToSNSUploadProgressNotificationTopicSubscription:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
    Properties:
      Endpoint: "$subscription_email_here"
      Protocol: "email"
      TopicArn: ${self:custom.uploadProgressNotificationTopicArn}
```

and then your lambda roles resource look like below (personally I separate the SNS and lambda roles resources into different yaml)

```
  Resources: 
    # Upload lambda roles
      UploadLambdaRole:
        Type: AWS::IAM::Role
        Properties:
          RoleName: ${self:custom.uploadLambdaRoleName}
          AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Principal:
                  Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
                Action:
                  - sts:AssumeRole
          Policies:
            - PolicyName: AccessUploadProgressNotificationSNSTopic
                PolicyDocument:
                  Statement:
                    - Effect: Allow
                      Action:
                        - "sns:*"
                      Resource: "${self:custom.uploadProgressNotificationTopicArn}"
```

and lastly you can use this lambda role in your lambda function like below

```
upload:
  handler: src/handler/upload-handler
  role: UploadLambdaRole
  ...
```

So what this functionality does is your lambda can fire an message to your SNS topic and SNS will forward the message to your email.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  MyTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      DisplayName: topic-display-name
      TopicName: topic-name
      Subscription:
        - Endpoint: email_address1@mail.com
          Protocol: email
        - Endpoint: email_address2@mail.com
          Protocol: email
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76101886/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).